# Multiple C# Channels, Same type, different names

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, channel

When using Channels in C#, I want to run multiple channels with the same base type, but this causes issues with DI. For instance

I want to have a high priority channel and a medium priority channel, both of type Issue. So setting it up it for DI it will look like

```
services.AddSingleton(channel.CreateUnbounded<Issue>()) // high priority
services.AddSingleton(channel.CreateUnbounded<Issue>()) // normal priority?


public async Task<bool> CreateHighPriorityIssues(Channel<Issue> channel) {}

public async Task<bool> CreateNormalPriorityIssues(Channel<Issue> channel) {}
```

This above obviously does not work, so how do I go about it without having to refactor all the base classes?

Only other option I can think of is implementing some sort of factory method.

Comment: So you want both channels to be available at the same time? How do you expect the class that receives the injected dependency to choose the right channel?

Comment: That is the question. I don't know if there is a way do this without going full on factory. Was hoping for something like we have with "Named HTTP Clients" or another work around.

Comment: No, I don't think that is your question. Your question is how to meet a requirement. I'm asking you what the requirement is to begin with. Why are there two channels and how do you choose one of them? E.g. do you have an `if` statement, like `if (user.Priority == Priority.High) channel = GetHighPriorityChannel()`...?

Comment: I have 1 worker service that will monitor two Channels for events. It needs to process High Priority events if there are any in that channel first. Or continue processing the Normal channel. Upstream the way the data enters the channel is dictated by an upstream services that will look at properties in the event (owner, client, description) and make an automated decision onto which channel to place the event.

Comment: @CasperPieterse Hi, did you had any update about this?

Answer (score 1):

Based on research there is no easy way to do this with Microsoft's built-in DI framework, which although easy to use is not as feature rich as some of the 3rd party DI frameworks out there.

To that end, I've decided to use Autofac instead that gives me the flexibility I need to call the right services via Named Services.

https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html